# How do i add a list of dicts to my sqlite database via sqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Case:
I have a generator that generates som keys together with a key-id and a customer name.

The generator outputs a list of dicts somethng like this:

```
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 2, 'key': 't0n8x0RCAwKJ'}
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 3, 'key': 'FvBCCg@p4u4m'}
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 4, 'key': 'pjiNONS9H9jS'}
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 5, 'key': 'gpf4uUO97rgG'}
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 6, 'key': 'U999n89Fgbdj'}
{'project': 'asdfasdfgg', 'key_id': 7, 'key': '1eHBuMQ8GTrE'}
```

I want to add this dict to my database and my code is the following:
main.py:

```
    class Keys(Base):
      __tablename__ = "keys"

      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      project = Column(String)
      key_id = Column(Integer)
      key = Column(String)



    def create_key(request: Request, project: str = Form(...), amount: int = Form(...), db: Session = 
    Depends(get_db)):

    keys = Keys()
    data_generated = streamticket.thekeygenerator.keydata.generator(amount, project)

    for d in data_generated:
        keys.project = i["project"]
        keys.key = i["key"]
        keys.key_id = i["key_id"]

        db.add(keys)
    db.commit()
```

My problem is that is is only the last dict/key that is added to the database. And my logic is that it updates the keys class and the database just gets updated and dont create a new row for each dict in the for loop.
I've read the documentation and to add multple items i can use db.add_all but I dont understand how i can use this is my case, since I'm only updating the keys model in each cycle..

Please be good to me, this is my first python project :-)

Comment: I don't see where the variable `i` is created. Your for-loop creates a variable called `d`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @mechanical_meat Sorry.. the post should say 'i' insted of 'd' i changed it to 'd' here on stack overflow. So that is not the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `Keys()` instance for each call to `db.add()`.

So, it becomes:

```py
data_generated = streamticket.thekeygenerator.keydata.generator(amount, project)

for d in data_generated:
    keys = Keys()
    keys.project = d["project"]
    keys.key = d["key"]
    keys.key_id = d["key_id"]
    db.add(keys)

db.commit()
```

---

It's because `db.add` expects a unique instance of `Keys`. Creating a single `Keys` instance rewrites it on each iteration, thus only inserting the last value. Also, see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects) and [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all).

By unique, I mean -

```py
class Person:
    pass

p1 = Person()
p2 = Person()

print(p1 == p1, p2 == p2)  # True True
print(p1 == p2)  # False
```

Comment: can you explain to me why i have to define it in each cycle?